# Expression Engine - Access Forbidden Issues

Tags: expressionengine

Whenever I have create a new template group in EE I can access that template group's index file as follows:

http://www.mysite.com/my_template_group/

However, I am working on a project and for the first time ever if I use that link I get the following error message:

> You do not have permission to access this directory.

If I include the index in the url it works fine:

```
http://www.mysite.com/my_template_group/index
```

What would be causing this snafu and how can I resolve it? Using the /index in the link is unacceptable.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an EE-generated error (using the EE user message design), or a plain-jane server error message (large black text on white)?

Comment: This is a server error message.

Comment: You don't just happen to have an empty folder in your site root with the same name as your template group?

Comment: Hi Derek, that is it. I just did a review of the root directory and there it was - a legacy calendar folder. Elevate your comment to an answer and you get the correct answer award.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't just happen to have an empty folder in your site root with the same name as your template group?

Comment: that was the problem. Thanks.